# Use different TypeScript `@types` for sub-dependencies with different versions

Tags: typescript

I use package A and B v1 in my application. Package A itself depends on B v2, and it seems like all `@types` packages use `*` for their dependency versions. This means that I can only have *either* B v1 or B v2 in `node_modules/@types/B`.

What I would expect is to have:

- v1 in `node_modules/@types/B` used in my application
- v2 in `node_modules/@types/A/node_modules/B` used by `A`

While writing this question I realised I could do `declare module 'A'; declare module 'B';` and just ignore all typings for both packages all together. Is there some other way, keeping the typings for the respective package? Is this not a design flaw in `@types` packages?